# Why might EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager() result in a NullPointerException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle10g

I am new to JPA.  My code trying to connect to an Oracle 10.3 database to populate some tables.  However, before it even gets to the code population, it throws a NullPointerException in EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(String).  I have already verified that the `emf` variable is not null. Here is the relevant code in Populator.java, which is just like many tutorial examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LeaveSchedulerJPA");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

The exception trace is:

```
[EL Severe]: 2012-10-11 14:37:02.415--ServerSession(37999235)--java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.ExceptionMessageGenerator.buildMessage(ExceptionMessageGenerator.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateServerSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.Populator.main(Populator.java:28)
```

My persistence.xml is below.  The specified URL works when I use it from Eclipse to generate classes corresponding to the tables.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LeaveSchedulerJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.Holiday</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.Leave</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.LeaveType</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.Notification</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.NotificationType</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.Role</class>
        <class>com.engilitycorp.leaveschedulerjpa.User</class>
        <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="leavescheduler"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The error does not like that it is yours... it tells that an error happened, but when it was going to find the resource bundle (a glorified properties file) to put the appropiate message in the exception it could not find the bundle. I would check that all the JPA jars are in the classpath. Then you will find the real error :-D

Comment: SJuan76: Thanks for the idea.  My application compiles just fine - all of the javax.persistence.* classes are found.  What might I need at run-time that isn't present at compile-time?  (I am both compiling and running from Eclipse.)

Comment: I don't know the structure of eclipse persistence as to tell you which jar is missing (assuming I am right), but if from that jar you only use the bundles then you would not see errors at compile time because the existence of the bundles is not checked then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out that I was trying to test the persistence as though it were a standalone Java application.  The documentation states that EntityManagerFactoryImpl maintains "a reference to the active ServerSession".  When I ran the same code within WebLogic, it worked fine.

A coworker was able to run the same code as a standalone Java application.  I haven't yet figured out what the critical configuration difference was.